# How to create trap with Firewalld

Tags: firewalld, firewalld-zone

I'd like to set up the following logic using **firewalld**

1. When a host attempts to access the server from the internet on port 22:

   1. DROP and
   2. add their IP to an ipset called "trap" (with 24 hour timeout)
2. When a host whose IP is on the "trap" list attempts to connect to any port: DROP.

I've read many doc pages but can't see how to implement 1.2 above.

Comment: Use `fail2ban`.

Comment: @AlexD yes, not a bad idea, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firewalld supports ipsets and you specify the 24 hour timeout (86400 seconds) when setting up that ipset:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-ipset=trap --type=hash:ip --option=timeout=86400
firewall-cmd --reload
```

In native net-filter / iptables the logic and ordering of the necessary rules would be:

```
# Block all traffic from IP-addresses in the trap ipset 
# (with REJECT to facilitate debugging) 

iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set  --match-set trap src -j REJECT 

# Add all IP-addresses to that connect to TCP port 22 to the trap ipset
# (the --timeout value is only necessary when different from the default for the ipset) 

iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp  -m tcp --dport 22  -m set  --add-set trap src --timeout 86400 -j SET 

# Reject access access to TCP port 22 for everybody

iptables -I INPUT 3 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

Translating that to native firewalld / firewall-cmd  rules/structures is bit beyond me at the moment, but adding the rules 1 & 2 as direct rules should be easy enough.

You should be able to get display  entries in the trap list with:

```
 firewall-cmd --permanent --ipset=trap  --get-entries
```

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, so firewalld doesn't have a facility for this. I'm migrating from firehol (which does).